# Setting up my source, build directories and make tool

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to set up a new C++ project. I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Source is under ~/repo/source/
2. Built files go to ~/repo/build/...
3. ~/repo/source should remain as clean as possible, at least I should be able to ignore any files that are written there using .gitignore entries
4. I can build from any directory under ~/repo/source (e.g. I can call "mymake" from under ~/repo/source/project1/lib1), and it will build and put the binaries under ~/repo/build
5. I can build debug or release binaries, and they go to their respective directories. e.g. "mymake --config=debug" or something similar.

This seems like the setup I have seen in every tech company I have worked for. I don't know enough about make tools though to do this. Can I use cmake to achieve the above? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use cmake to achieve the above?

yes:

1. -
2. Yes, assuming that your `CMakeLists.txt` is in `~/repo/source/`, you run either `cmake ../source`from `~/repo/build/` (or absolute path) dir or use the gui with that path. But normaly the `build` is placed within your project (`~/repo/source/build`) and eg. added to git ignore since it's not designated for sharing. Just run `cmake ..` from there.
3. No problem, all local / generated files are within the `build` dir (see #2); add this to `.gitignore`. For sharing your project: just don't share `build`.
4. You have to run cmake with the path where your root `CMakeLists.txt` is. But: child-dirs can have their own lists.
5. Yes.